# Usage Tracking in Azure synapse analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics

Can anyone share a Kusto query (KQL) that I can use in log analytics that would return some usage tracking stats?

I am trying to identify which "Views" and "Tables" are used the most. Also trying to find out who the power users are and commands/query that is run against the "Tables".

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below functions to gather the useage statics
DiagnosticMetricsExpand()
DiagnosticLogsExpand()
ActivityLogRecordsExpand()

And create target tables to store the function data to analyse the useage information.

Refer the Azure documentation for complete details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-no-code?tabs=activity-logs

Tutorial: Ingest monitoring data in Azure Data Explorer without code

In this tutorial, you learn how to ingest monitoring data to Azure Data Explorer without one line of code and query that data.